# Optimizing seldom used varchar fields

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm a developer with some limited database knowledge, trying to put together a scalable DB design for a new app.  Any thoughts that anyone could provide on this problem would be appreciated.

Assume I currently have the following table:

```
Stuff
------------
ID  Integer
Attr1   Integer
Attr2   Integer
Attr3   Double
Attr4   TinyInt
Attr5   Varchar(250)
```

Looking forward, assume we will have 500 million records in this table.  However, at any given time only 5000 or so records will have anything in the Attr5 column; all other records will have a blank or null Attr5 column.  The Attr5 column is populated with 100-200 characters when a record is inserted, then a nightly process will clear the data in it.

My concern is that such a large varchar field in the center of a tablespace that otherwise contains mostly small numeric fields will decrease the efficiency of reads against the table.  As such, I was wandering if it might be better to change the DB design to use two tables like this:

```
Stuff
------------
ID  Integer
Attr1   Integer
Attr2   Integer
Attr3   Double
Attr4   TinyInt

Stuff_Text
------------
StuffID Integer
Attr5   Varchar(250)
```

Then just delete from Stuff_Text during the nightly process keeping it at 5,000 records, thus keeping the Stuff table minimal in size.

So my question is this: Is it necessary to break this table into two, or is the database engine intelligent enough to store and access the information efficiently?  I could see the DB compressing the data efficiency and storing records without data in Attr5 as if there was no varchar column.  I could also see the DB leaving an open 250 bytes of data in every record anticipating data for Attr5.  I tend to expect the former, as I thought that was the purpose of varchar over char, but my DB experience is limited so I figure I'd better double check.

I am using MySQL 5.1, currently on Windows 2000AS, eventually upgrading to Windows Server 2008 family.  Database is currently on a standard 7200 rpm magnetic disc, eventually to be moved to an SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Stuff
------------
ID     Integer
Attr1  Integer
Attr2  Integer
Attr3  Double
Attr4  TinyInt
Attr5  Integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 (build an index on this)

Stuff_Text
------------
Attr5_id   Integer (primary key)
Attr5_text Varchar(250)
```

In action

```
desc select * from Stuff WHERE Attr5<>0;

desc select Stuff.*, Stuff_text.Attr5_text 
from Stuff
inner join Stuff_text ON Stuff.Attr5=Stuff_text.Attr5_id;
```

1. don't store NULL
2. make use on integer as foreign key
3. when pulling of record `where Attr5 <>0   <-- scan 5,000 rows`
4. much smaller index size
5. **do a benchmark yourself**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `VARCHAR` and allowing `NULL` values, then you shouldn't have problems. Becouse it's really efficient storing this kind of datatype. This is very different from `CHAR` datatype, but you already has `VARCHAR`.

Anyway, splitting it into two tables is not a bad idea. This could be good to keep the query cache alive, but it mostly depends in the use these tables have.

Last thing i can say: Try to benchmark it. Instert a bulk of data and try to simulate some use.